# GET with Angular and Parse.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, get

I just started using http://parse.com and I'm wanting to get some data that is previously stored. Everything I've tried seems that it should be working, but I have a feeling that parse doesn't work real well with AngularJS for some reason.

Here's my JS and HTML:

```js
app.controller('FoodLog', function($scope) {
      Parse.initialize("XXXXXX", "XXXXXX");

      $scope.foodItems = [];

      var Food = Parse.Object.extend("Food");
      var parseFoodItems = new Parse.Query(Food);
      parseFoodItems.find({
        success: function(results) {

          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var food_name = results[i].get('name');
            var food_protein = results[i].get('protein');
            var food_carbs = results[i].get('carbs');
            var food_fat = results[i].get('fat');

            $scope.foodItems.push({
              name: food_name,
              protein: food_protein,
              carbs: food_carbs,
              fat: food_fat,
              calories: (food_protein * 4) + (food_carbs * 4) + (food_fat * 9)
            });
          }
        },
        error: function(error) {
          alert("something broke" + " " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
      });
```

```html
<div class="menu-items">
  <div ng-repeat="item in foodItems">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#food-{{$index}}">
      {{item.name}}
    </button>
    <div id="food-{{$index}}" class="collapse">
      <ul>
        <li>Protein: {{item.protein}}g</li>
        <li>Carbs: {{item.carbs}}g</li>
        <li>Fat: {{item.fat}}g</li>
        <li>Total Calories: {{item.calories}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the correct keys for Parse, and I've also tried outputting to the console after I've pushed to my foodItems array, and the items are being pushed, they're just not being picked up by Angular. If I hard code items into the array, they display just fine in my HTML.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You probably just need to run `$scope.$apply()` at the end of the Parse callback functions

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much Phil!! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Phil, it was a simple $scope.$apply(); at the end of my "success:" function. Thanks!